# Does any IDE offer similar functionality as Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, ide

I'm a beginner in Python and have been using Jupyter notebook as recommended by my teacher. I want to build some larger scripts now however so I am looking to start using an IDE.

In the Jupyter notebook if you press "Shift+Tab" after calling a function you get the following message:

[image]

i.e. you can bring up the function documentation.

I have tried PyCharm and Spyder and both don't have this feature as far as I know, at least to the extent of Jupyter. Mostly, they have a message which shows what parameters the function takes but does not show the doc string or anywhere near the detail Jupyter shows.

Does anyone know if any IDE has this information? It is just very useful for someone learning to quickly press shift+tab and see all the information of a function

Comment: in pycharm i believe it is ctrl+q by default, you can find it under settings>keymap>mainmenu>view>quick documentation

Comment: Thanks, turns out it is called "inspect current object"! It is ctrl+I for Spyder also

Answer (score 1):

## Sublime Text 3

Sublime Text 3 is where it is at! Check out the image below (The documentation in that image shows up when you finish typing the function, no need to even hit a key command to get the list of parameters):

[image: Python Help in Sublime Text 3]

Not only does this text editor rock, it is fully extensible and has a huge community of people developing tools for it. One of those tools is an Anaconda package that functions right in the editor. Although I still use Jupyter sometimes for the line-by-line read out everyone is used to, I pretty much only use Sublime.

### Other sublime info:

In addition to the python specific packages, sublime has a whole slew of useful add-ons: Git plugins, linters, plus you can customize the key commands whatever way you see fit.

[Sublime Text 3](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiWq6exo5rRAhWl0YMKHUZKC2kQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sublimetext.com%2F3&usg=AFQjCNG99v3saFvWz9d8u0KgvjFVcunN9A&bvm=bv.142059868,d.amc)